# how to install wordpress HyperDB

Tags: multisite, hyperdb

Can anyone help me installing Wordpress multi-site. I want to Partition my database. Suppose I want to use 1 database for 300 blogs and I am expecting to have 10000 blogs. So I will need 33/34 database. (I am not sure about the calculation would be helpful if anyone can help me about the how many blogs for 1 database. I am not sure how many blogs a database can hold.)

So how can I setup it?

```
$wpdb->add_database(array(
    'host'     => 'global.db.example.com',
    'user'     => 'globaluser',
    'password' => 'globalpassword',
    'name'     => 'globaldb',
));

$wpdb->add_database(array(
    'host'     => 'blog.db1.example.com',
    'user'     => 'bloguser1',
    'password' => 'blogpassword',
    'name'     => 'blogdb1',
    'dataset'  => 'blog_one',
));

$wpdb->add_database(array(
    'host'     => 'blog.db2.example.com',
    'user'     => 'bloguser2',
    'password' => 'blogpassword',
    'name'     => 'blogdb2',
    'dataset'  => 'blog_two',
));
```

And so on? (this is just a theory)

How my new blogs will move to those database? When new blog sign up how it will move to new database?

Most important this is how can I tell how many database to move to this database and how many to move that database?

Comment: This might be a little too specific to HyperDB to get good answers here, working with it isn't very generic skill in WP dev.

Comment: The readme says:
> How does HyperDB support partitioning?
> HyperDB allows tables to be placed in arbitrary databases. It can use callbacks you write to compute the appropriate database for a given query. Thus you can partition your site's data according to your own scheme and configure HyperDB accordingly.

Comment: There's a super minimal example in the provided config file of the plugin, but documentation is poor to near nonexistent, and usage of hyperdb isn't widespread. Also HyperDB won't move your data. You can tell it were to write, were to read, load balance etc, but replication and migration must be done using other tools, at which point you're not longer in WordPress territory, you're in Server and Database admin territory

Comment: ok so you are saying that if i want to replication the database then I need to copy the master database to slave database every time a new post or user or some thing happens, with some other technology which is out of wordpress scop.. right?

anyway right now I am not doing it. I want to make databases and tell hyperdb that write 2 - 300 blog in this database and 301 too 600 to that database.... or slimier thing (which is the best option)... how can i do that?

Comment: I am still poor in coding... and working with such case..!! can you please help me to build the logic? As you @TomJNowell said I can write my own scheme.. but I don't have that much logic build yet... can you write a bit of code for this scenario ( 33 database and how to tell where to write in which query) thanks :)

Comment: @BlackReaper as it says in the plugins readme, HyperDB doesn't do replication, you need to sort that out separately, and it's not a WordPress things, it's a database server thing, the sort of stuff you'd need to ask server admins not WordPress developers. Also, answers here should answer your question, a copy pasta code snippet would not answer your question. Note that there is a super simple example in db config that demonstrates how to choose which database to use

Answer (score 1):

The theory behind how HyperDB and such plugins work is that they use a simple calculation on the blog number to allocate a DB for it at creation time, and access it later. I am not sure what exactly happens when you need do add a new DB server, you will either need to look at the code or ask for support from the author.... looking at the code seems like to can associate blogs with groups which I assume can be associated with specific servers but you probably don't want to use this functionality unless you need it (move a very active blog).

As for the number of DBs needed, It depends very much on the load they are going to have, but your estimate of having a 33 sites per DB sounds to me as too conservative. I ran a multisite as big (30+ blogs) on a relatively low level VPS and had no performance problems with it. In the end it will depend on usage and caching, but I think you can get to 100 blogs per DB with proper caching being applied (memcache probably). Anyway the nice thing about having DB servers is that it is easy to upgrade a specific one if it gets hammered more than the others.

Comment: no I mean 300 blogs in one db.. 10000 blogs in 33 databases... 
I need example code which i can use or modify...

Comment: here goes my reading comprehension :), but it does not change the answer @BlackReaper

Comment: thanks you... I like the idea to move active blog in another database... but as I said I am expecting to have more than 10000 blogs and doing it manually is not easy... so I am looking for a bit of code or logic...

Comment: With all due respect if you **need** something you should hire someone for that to tailor a solution for you. The answers on this site are about concepts and there is no guaranty they will work "as  is" for anyone

Comment: As @tom said, not many use it, and if he is not feeling comfortable to give an answer, while he is working for a biggest company using it, I will not even try to guess what is the right/best code for it

Comment: I am sorry if my replay was rough... as I said I like your answer but I am looking for more... I have been searching all over the internet no help.. and If by any chance anyone can give me a suggestion would be win win situation for me.. :)

Comment: that wasn't rough, but many people think answers are supposed to be a solution to the question, while this is not how the site works, so in generle people that asking for something extremly specific might waste there time waiting for a good answer here

Comment: As @TomJNowell said I can configure Hyperdb using callbacks to site's data according to your own scheme and configure HyperDB accordingly... I need this logic only.. maybe any code help... if possible...

Comment: ok @MarkKaplun I get that... :)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use MultiDB for this:
https://github.com/wpmudev/multi-db

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the plugin is not active and maintained by the developer

Comment: @BlackReaper the instructions on that site can be useful, even though that plugin isn’t maintained. But it make 16-6000k databases. Last time I’ve checked, it still works well. Maybe someone forked it and continued maintaining it elsewhere?